# checking whether the C compiler works... no; configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

Tags: macos, gcc, cabal

I am using OSx, attempting to install a haskell package 'SDL-mixer' via 'cabal install SDL-mixer'. I get the following error:

```
$ cabal install SDL-mixerResolving dependencies...
Configuring SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0...
Failed to install SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0
Build log ( /Users/matthewherzl/.cabal/logs/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0.log ):
cabal: Entering directory '/var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0'
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( /var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0/dist/setup/setup.hs, /var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0/dist/setup/Main.o )
Linking /var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0/dist/setup/setup ...
Configuring SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0...
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-compiler
checking for sdl-config... /usr/local/bin/sdl-config
checking for gcc... /usr/bin/clang
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.
cabal: Leaving directory '/var/folders/v7/gzwp_4j12gd_3d2pt2cl52yr0000gn/T/cabal-tmp-7633/SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0'
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
SDL-mixer-0.6.2.0 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 77
```

Other questions pose similar errors, but I have not found a solution that works for my case.

Some things I've tried:

- validated that gcc is present on my machine, and works to successfully compile a c program.
- restarted my machine
- removed and reinstalled xcode
- uninstalled and reinstalled gcc
- installed clang
- attempted to install in sandbox

I get the same error in each case.

It seems there is something I need to change in my OS setup; any ideas on how to fix?